# Bing maps hides infobox when view changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps for displaying some `pushpins` and `infoboxes` created by users, and it's working fine. However, the open `infobox` disappears when the user switches between views, for instance when switching from `Road view` to `satellite` or `Bird's eye`. Is there any way I could handle that event and keep the `infobox` open? below some code

```
//For showing location 
const showLocation = (location, onInfoBoxClick, pushpinClick) => {
clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
hideInfobox();
const latVal = location.get('lat');
const longVal = location.get('long');
const locationId = location.get('id');
const pinLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latVal, longVal);
const infoBoxContainer = document.getElementById('infoBoxContainer');
const offsetWidth = infoBoxContainer.offsetWidth;
const offsetHeight = infoBoxContainer.offsetHeight;

const pushpinInfoBoxHolder = document.createElement('div');
pushpinInfoBoxHolder.id = 'pushpinInfoBoxHolder';
pushpinInfoBoxHolder.style.width = offsetWidth + 'px';
pushpinInfoBoxHolder.style.height = offsetHeight + 'px';

const infoBoxHTML = infoBoxContainer.innerHTML;

const pinInfoBox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(
  pinLocation,
  {
    visible: true,
    htmlContent: pushpinInfoBoxHolder.outerHTML,
    // the infobox needs to be shifted just a slight bit more than half it's width,
    // hence the X cordinate value, The Y co-ordinate value is a number arrived by
    // trial and is constant
    offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-(offsetWidth / 2 + 2), 58)
  }
);
```

I tried to capture event with below handler but not succeeded

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchangeend', () => {//showinfobox function}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We're going to need to see some code. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you show your code for how you're adding the pushpin to the map?

Comment: None of the current Bing Maps web controls do that do. What version are you using?